# When to dispatch_release()?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, grand-central-dispatch

I'm fairly new to GCD and was trying to find an answer to this. Assuming I have the following code:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("queue", NULL);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    // do some stuff
});
```

**Where in the code should I release the queue?** Inside or outside the block?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Outside the block. I'm fairly certain you don't have to wait for the async block to finish as GCD will retain the queue.