# What is the recommended pattern for the following GCD / blocks scenario?

Tags: objective-c, macos, memory-management, objective-c-blocks

I have a question about Grand Central Dispatch, blocks and memory management. Consider this code:

```
Worker *myWorker = [[Worker alloc] init];
[work doAsyncStuffWithBlock:^(NSMutableDictionary *info)
{
    NSLog(@"processing info results");
}];
[myWorker release];
```

Here, I want the doAsyncStuffWithBlock to happen asynchronously and then perform the block when it has some results.  Meanwhile this main code will continue on. Is it safe here to release myWorker? Will the dispatch_queue I implement internally keep a reference of it around to eventually execute that block? Or, should I release it inside the block? that seems weird.  Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: The code you posted does nothing with `myWorker` except initialization and releasing: it will be deallocated immediately. Also, you code does not show anything about the mentioned dispatch queue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a block references an Objective-C object, e.g.:

```
Worker *myWorker = [[Worker alloc] init];
[work doAsyncStuffWithBlock:^(NSMutableDictionary *info)
{
    NSLog(@"processing info results");
    [myWorker doSomething];
}];
[myWorker release];
```

it automatically retains that object and, when the block is released, it automatically releases that object.

So yes, you should release `myWorker` in your code, and no, you shouldn’t release `myWorker` inside the block.

Answer (score 1):

Read

- [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510765/what-is-the-correct-way-to-release-a-gcd-dispatch-queue-property)
- [or this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842460/when-to-dispatch-release)

You can release outside the block.

Comment: Good links, but answer is way too short.